# I have something curious about the nodejs usb module

Tags: node.js, usb, libusb, pkg-config

```
> usb@0.3.11 install /node_modules/usb
> node shyp-blacklist.js win32-x64 win32-ia32 darwin-x64 || node-gyp rebuild

Package libusb-1.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libusb-1.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libusb-1.0' found
gyp: Call to 'pkg-config libusb-1.0 --libs' returned exit status 1.
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/server/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:337:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:797:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-573.18.1.el6.x86_64
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/server/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /node_modules/usb
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.26
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.12.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! usb@0.3.11 install: `node shyp-blacklist.js win32-x64 win32-ia32 darwin-x64 || node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the usb@0.3.11 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the usb package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node shyp-blacklist.js win32-x64 win32-ia32 darwin-x64 || node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls usb
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-573.18.1.el6.x86_64
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/server/nodejs/bin/node" "/usr/local/server/nodejs/bin/npm" "i" "usb@0.3.11"
npm ERR! cwd /
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I don't know what that means! Any help would be appreciated! For example pkg_config search path is not found. I am wandering because I can't find the'libusb-1.0' path.

few